# PHP setcookie not showing if nothing is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, setcookie

So what i want to make and what i have problems with!

1. The "all" is not showing if the user haven't selected a currency!
2. How to write the code so if the "all" is loaded it uses the code from the individual if's per currency
3. How to delete the the use of `<input type="submit" value="Select currency">` button so its automatic change when a Currency is selected

(inside the `<body>`)

So how to delete the use of `<input type="submit" value="Select currency">` button so its automatic change when a Currency is selected?

```html
<form action="currency_switcher.php" method="post">
    <select name="money">
        <option value="all"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "all" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>All Currencies</option>
        <option value="IDR"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "IDR" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Indonesia RP</option>
        <option value="AUD"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "AUD" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Australian Dollars</option>
        <option value="USD"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "USD" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>American Dollars</option>
        <option value="SGD"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "SGD" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Singapore Dollars</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Select currency">
</form>
```

So the "all" is not showing if the user haven't selected a currency!

And how to write the code so the code from example IDR showing if ALL currency is loaded so i dont need to have the code two times written!.

```html
<?php

    if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "all") {

    echo "code";
    echo "code IDR";
    echo "code";
    echo "code AUD";
    echo "code";
    echo "code USD";
    echo "code";
    echo "code SGD";
    }


    if ( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "IDR" ) {

    echo "code IDR";
    }

    if ( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "AUD" ) {

    echo "code AUD";
    }

    if ( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "USD" ) {

    echo "code USD";
    }

    if ( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "SGD" ) {

    echo "code SGD";
    }

    ?>
```

The currency_switcher.php

```html
<?
$money = "all";
if( isset( $_POST["money"] ) ) {
    $money = $_POST["money"];
    setcookie ( 'currency', $money, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/', 'exampledomain.com');
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the cookie example:

```
$first_name = 'David'; setcookie('first_name',$first_name,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Getting the cookie:

```
echo 'Hello '.($_COOKIE['first_name']!='' ? $_COOKIE['first_name'] : 'Guest'); // Hello David!
```

Or set the cookie with more specific directives, for example:

```
setcookie('first_name',$first_name,time() + (86400* 7),'/~sugar/','davidwalsh.name',true,true);
```

Comment: DavidWalsh i was on that page just a couple of minutes a go!.. But i have set the $money = "all"; already!

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this more for you.

Comment: By default, make it select something? Therefore it will show setcookie

Comment: Maybe your right maybe is not setting anything is the start PHP!.. But i dont understand the code.. so!.. im not sure how to set it!..

Comment: Make one of the values you use "default"

Comment: For example. " <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>" the option with the value "audi" is selected.

Comment: I got the $money = 'all'; before the <body> and <option value="all"<?php if( $_COOKIE["currency"] == "all" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>All Currencies</option> so that should be covered right.. if not the starting code before the <body> dont work correctly!..